# Struggling to decide on instance size for Win10 VM

Tags: windows-10

Very basic question here. We are a charity looking to leverage a Win10 VM to run our old Sage 50 application as interim measure before we move to Cloud based accounting software.

I'm a bit stuck on the azure pricing model and which tier I should select. We'll likely be powering the VM up and down as we need to use it, and we don't really need something performant, just useable to input in the software.

Can anyone recommend which cheapest instance size would fit the bill for this usecase?

Thanks in advance for all suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft do have a sizing guide here:[Virtual Machine Sizing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/virtual-machine-recs)

Start with the smallest and scale up to a level of performance you're comfortable with.

[image: Sizing Chart]